# Gnuradio 3.8.0 With Python3 Release Version Have Not Compatible Python3 Xmlrpc Library How I Can Fix İt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnuradio

First I create a osmocom-sink signal-source and Xmlrpc-server. I want to use rcp commands to change cent_frequency. İt give to me this error

```
****Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u /root/Downloads/xmlsiz.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Downloads/xmlsiz.py", line 20, in <module>
    import SimpleXMLRPCServer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SimpleXMLRPCServer'
>>> Done (return code 1)****
```

I Fixed it. I changed library name to

import SimpleXMLRPCServer

from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

But İt is giving to me this error again !

```
root@kali:~/Downloads# python3 '/root/Downloads/xmlsiz.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Downloads/xmlsiz.py", line 157, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/Downloads/xmlsiz.py", line 135, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "/root/Downloads/xmlsiz.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.xmlrpc_server_0 = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8080), allow_none=True)
AttributeError: type object 'SimpleXMLRPCServer' has no attribute 'SimpleXMLRPCServer'
```

How Can I Fix This ?  Gnuradio 3.8.0 python3 version is not compatible Python3 Xmlrpc Library.

Comment: Which Linux distribution do you use and which version? How did you install gnuradio? Is xmlsiz.py generated from a flowgraph (.grc) and have you regenerated it using gnuradio 3.8? Is xmlsiz.py an open source project and could you give us a download link?

Comment: I am using Linux kali 5.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.3.7-1kali1 (2019-10-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux  .  I updated and Upgraded last version kali linux.  I installed Gnuradio from kali linux resiptory with ( apt-get install gnuradio). yes xmlsiz.py is generated with Gnuradio 3.8 . No grc flowgraph.   My Screenshot picture is this :  https://i.hizliresim.com/lQXdYl.png

Comment: ..   İt is working perfect without xmlrpc block. But I need to change value osmocom-sink So I need xmlrpc block to change center frequency when I am talking to microfone.  Yes I uploaded that my project  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YrBcyhCEJCXvqablJU4uXGlCx-n29cxV/view?usp=sharing    you can download it.

Answer (score 0):

> How Can I Fix This ? Gnuradio 3.8.0 python3 version is not compatible Python3 Xmlrpc Library.

It turns out the `XMLRPC Server` block in gnuradio 3.8 is still not ported to python3, this issue is reported in https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/2782

> ```
>   File "/root/Downloads/xmlsiz.py", line 81, in __init__
>     self.xmlrpc_server_0 = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8080), allow_none=True) 
> AttributeError: type object 'SimpleXMLRPCServer' has no attribute 'SimpleXMLRPCServer'
> ```

Try changing line 81 to

```
self.xmlrpc_server_0 = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8080), allow_none=True)
```